# Problem converting columns from character to factor using across within mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I am encountering a problem when I run the following code to try to convert several columns of data from character to factor:

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

"LR_df1"<-read_excel("Correct file location.xlsx",sheet="Correct sheet")


LR_df1 %>%
  as_tibble()%>%
  mutate(across(c(SiteCode, S01UsualResidence), as.factor))
```

The initial output looks good, and it appears that the specified columns have been converted:

```
    # A tibble: 1,075 x 238
       A CaseId SiteCode S01Gender S01UsualResidence
   <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>    <chr>     <fct>
```

But then when I run:

```
summary(LR_df1$SiteCode)
```

I get:

`> summary(LR_df1$SiteCode) Length     Class      Mode  1075 character character`

So it appears that the variable hasn't been converted. I'd be very grateful to anyone who can show me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This is because you did not save your output back to `LR_df1`.

Answer (score 1):

`mutate()`, like all other functions from `dplyr`, doesn't permanently change the dataframe it works on. On its own, it will output a changed dataframe, but the original dataframe stays intact.

If you want it to permanently change the dataframe, you need to reassign:

```r
LR_df1 <- LR_df1 |> mutate(...)
```

Comment: Thank you. Just learning to use dplyr and this is very helpful!